# Android 12 and material you detection

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, material-components

I'm trying to update my theme with the new Material You, it's working when I select a color in Android parameter (Screenshot red part) but when I disable it (blue part) I've got the default value color set in the SDK xml.
Example with: @android:color/system_accent1_0

I want to know how to check when user select it or not (red or blue part in screenshot), this way i will use another theme when disable. I guess I need to use the new method: applyToActivitiesIfAvailable :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(this, R.style.AppDynamicTheme, (activity, themeResId) -> {
        // ...implement your own logic here. Return `true` if dynamic colors should be applied.
        return true; // <- How to know if it's enable or disable in Android parameter ?
});}
```

My 2nd question is about the icon of the application, when i put blank color in background of ic_launcher.xml it works but not with another color, do you know why ?

Thanks

[image: Android 12 material you cokors]